# Having trouble passing array to function

Tags: visual-c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am getting all kinds of errors when passing my array to this function. The function is suppose to have the user enter a name and a score and store them in 2 seperate arrays, one for the names, one for the scores. I believe I have to use pointers but have no idea on how to use them. I don't want the answer, just a push in the right direction. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int InputData(int &, char, int);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char playerName[100][20];
    int score[100];
    int numPlayers = 0;

    InputData(numPlayers, playerName, score);
    return 0;
}

int InputData(int &numPlayers, char playerName[][20], int score[])
{
    while (numPlayers <= 100)
    {
        cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
        cin.getline(playerName, 100, ‘\n’);
        if ((playerName[numPlayers] = 'Q') || (playerName[numPlayers] = 'q'))
        return 0;
        cout << "Enter score for " << playerName[numPlayers] <<": ";
        cin >> score[numPlayers];
        numPlayers++;
    }
}
```

Ok, I made some more changes and the errors are less, must be getting close, Lol!

Comment: I've spent the last 15 minutes looking at this and I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly.  Why do you have a multidimensional array for playerName?  Are you storing only one score per player or can each player have multiple scores?

Comment: Fraser - return type of `main()` should be **int**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a school assignment and I applaud you for not asking for the answer.  There are several ways to do it, but you are already fairly close in the approach that you are using.  When you pass an array reference, you do not want to include the length of the array.  For example, the parameter `int score[100]` should be `int score[]`. The exception, especially in your scenario, is with multidimensional arrays.  In this case, you want to use `char playerName[][20]`.  Your function declaration also needs to change to match.  Don't forget InputData returns an int.  Your declarations and function call are correct; you just need to adjust your function signature.

Comment: He needs to pass numPlayers by reference also.  He is also changing the score array but has no counter to keep track of those changes. There is quite a lot wrong with the code.  I hope he edits his question or responds with some more details.

Comment: I made some changes, but I am plain stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the errors aside -

```
InputData(numPlayers, playerName, score, size);
                                      // ^^^^ size is no where declared
                                      // resulting Undeclared indentifier error
```

Prototype mentions of taking 3 arguments but calling the function passing 4 parameters.

**Hint regarding errors:**

- An 1D array decays to a pointer pointing to first element in the array while passing to a function.
- A 2D array decays to a pointer pointing to the 1D array ( i.e., T[][size] ) while passing to a function.
- Return type of `main()` should be **int**.

---

It seems with the given hints you corrected most of the errors. But you forgot to change the prototype. So, change -

```
int InputData(int &, char, int);
```

to

```
int InputData(int &, char[][20], int[]);
```

Why aren't you using [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) array for player names ? Use it and remove rest of the errors. Good luck.

Comment: @Dave Fraser - Since it seems a homework, with the given hints you should be able to solve it. One more hint: The prototype of `InputData(..)` isn't matching it's definition arguments.

Comment: @ Mahesh I understand they are converted to pointers when entering the function, my problem is assigning the array values to pointer variables. How do you do this?